# How to ignore duplicate inserts with datamapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper

I have a datamapper model that has a unique index on a property called name. I want to create new records when a name doesn't already exist and silently ignore attempts to create records with duplicate names. What's the "right" way to do this in datamapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer is to use first_or_create, which as Dan points out above, is already built into datamapper and therefore doesn't need to be declared.

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-validations'

class Committer
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String, :unique_index => true
  validates_present :name
  validates_is_unique :name
end
committer = "George"
record = Committer.first_or_create(:name => committer)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use the dm-validations gem, and ensure that your name property is specified as being unique, eg:

```
class Committer
  include DataMapper::Resource

  # ... other properties ...

  property :name, String, :length => 1..100, :required => true, :unique => true
end
```

The dm-validations gem will introspect your model and automatically setup validations for your properties. In this case it won't allow more than one Committer to have the same name.

Comment: Thanks Dan. My main concern is not how to enforce uniqueness, but how to do an INSERT IGNORE--that is, how to create a new record but fail silently if a duplicate record is already there. I'm wondering what the best way of doing this is.

Comment: You can't do an INSERT IGNORE in DataMapper without a plugin, but there isn't one that does this atm.

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't mean to specifically require the use of INSERT IGNORE. Anything that accomplished my goal was fine.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I came up with is simply to ignore the exception:

```
  begin
    Committer.create!(:name => committer)
  rescue DataObjects::IntegrityError => e # ignore duplicate inserts
  end
```

If you have a better (more idiomatic) way of doing it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution I came up with:

```
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-validations'
require 'dm-more'
record = Committer.find_or_create(:name => committer)
```

If you're using this in sinatra, requiring dm-more seems to cause
other problems. My solution was to require my own file that only
contained the following code:

```
module DataMapper
 module Model
   def first_or_create(conditions = {}, attributes = {})
     first(conditions) || create(conditions.merge(attributes))
   end

   alias find_or_create first_or_create
 end
end
```

Comment: The `Model#first_or_create` method is already part of DataMapper. Also I wouldn't generally recommend using finders named `#find_*` because they might conflict with other plugins like dm-ar-finders; but more importantly the DataMapper naming convention for finders that return the first of something is to use the `#first_*` prefix.